# Repeatable xml form field - Can't remove fields / Repeatable.js issue

Tags: development, joomla-3.3.x, bugs, form

I am playing around with the new repeatable form field in my component.
I am getting a few js errors.

Chosen

> repeatable.js:187
>   TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   '$('select').chosen({
>                   disable_search_threshold : 10,
>                   allow_single_deselect : true
>               })')

Remove

> repeatable.js:160
>   TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
>   (evaluating 'tr.remove()')

I guess the Chosen error is because the chosen.js is not loaded. Are there any other specific steps to take, in order to have the chosen.js loaded ?

As for the jQuery remove function method, I can't figure this out. jQuery is loaded at the top of the document, but it still can't evaluate the function.

Attaching a screenshot with the issues and the head contents of the page. Any input/feedback is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Apparently they "fixed" a bug with the repeatable form field but appear to have caused another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously and from the comments, the Repeatable Form Field is still very buggy and under development. Therefore we shall wait for some time for it.

Comment: Are you able to update/improve this answer? It doesn't feel like an answer.